# getting error "no signer available" when logging the signer seems to work fine

Tags: metamask, ethers.js

I am putting together a simple application that connects a user's metamask and then has some buttons that call the functions of a contract that i've deployed on the porcini testnet.

This is the function that is called when I click on the increment button to increment the counter by 1.

```
const handleIncrement = useCallback(async () => {
    console.log("calling contract function increment()");
    if (!signer) {
      console.error("No signer available, please connect wallet");
      return;
    }
    try {
      const abi = await fetchAbi();
      await incrementCount(abi, signer);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error executing increment: ", error);
    }
  }, [signer]);
```

This then calls the incrementCount() function which is in another file and is as follows:

```
export const incrementCount = async (abi, signer) => {
  console.log(signer);
  console.log(abi);
  const contractWithSigner = new ethers.Contract(CONTRACT_ADDRESS, abi, signer);
  const tx = await contractWithSigner.increment();
  console.log(tx);
};
```

logging the signer gives me this:

```
JsonRpcSigner {_isSigner: true, provider: JsonRpcProvider, _address: '0xf126c7Ce40F9A8ecDcf8570736E2be2dFAA24967', _index: null}
```

logging the contractWithSigner gives me this:

```
Contract {interface: Interface, provider: JsonRpcProvider, signer: JsonRpcSigner, callStatic: {…}, estimateGas: {…}, …}
```

For context im setting the provider in a useEffect like this:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setProvider(
      new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
        getPublicProviderUrl("porcini", false),
        7672
      )
    );
  }, []);
```

however I get this error when I try to run this transaction:

```
index.js:147 Error executing increment:  Error: processing response error (body="{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"error\":{\"code\":-32603,\"message\":\"no signer available\"},\"id\":46}", error={"code":-32603}, requestBody="{\"method\":\"eth_sendTransaction\",\"params\":[{\"gas\":\"0x674f\",\"from\":\"0xf126c7ce40f9a8ecdcf8570736e2be2dfaa24967\",\"to\":\"0xcf1b2e11c7329f3a73ac62f0cfc66d0225a42f78\",\"data\":\"0xd09de08a\"}],\"id\":46,\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\"}", requestMethod="POST", url="https://porcini.rootnet.app/archive", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.7.1)
```

This confuses me because it seems like i've passed in the provider and thus the signer correctly but the error is telling me otherwise...are there some other steps i need to take in order to be able to prompt the user to sign this transaction in their metamask?